# Can't allow programs to make changes and opening in admin

Tags: windows-10, administrator

I'm using Windows 10 and can't open any program in admin mode. When I click to run a program in admin, a window to ask If the program can make changes in the device should appear, but this is the problem: It freezes in that overlay part that shows up behind the window but the window never shows up, I can force It  to appear with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> but doing this opens those options to change password, block computer and open task manager and the window that ask me the permission to make changes appears but only for a while and even if I click yes it doesn't do anything.

My user is admin in this machine and it's updated. In fact, I suspect this is update problem, a coworker described this problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I restarted my computer and after that the error doesn't show anymore. When I posted the question I had tried restarting, but I had to restart a couple times to make it work.